# RaspberryPi: Load cells and HX711 amplifier

Tags: amplifier, raspberry-pi, wire, load-cell

I've created an app that will read 10 weighing scales at the same time with separate values but since some wires are like 1 meter long, I get so much noises in the values.

1. I just wanna know if what's the best way to minimize the noises?
2. Which is better? HX711 near the Raspberry Pi or HX711 near the load cells?

Comment: That question is a bit broad.  Since the HX711 digitizes, if you can get the digital communication to work at a distance, then minimizing the analog run would be good.  Think very carefully about power filtering...

Comment: How much noise do you get? from the noisiest? from the quietest? What are the 10 Code Spreads, RMS? Are the distributions random Gaussian? or bi-modal (noise on, then noise off, then noise on, then noise off)? have you implemented capacitive filters on the VDD---GND nodes of the load cells>?